# while(rs.next()) overwrites data although I'm using a vector

Tags: java, jdbc, vector

I'm trying to read a table on a local Database through a Data Access Object .
for each row, I want to create an object that contains the informations of the row.
I used a vector inside the while(rs.next()) loop so that each iteration fills a cell with an object .
But I get this error : the object in the last row is filling all the cells of the vector.
I don't understand why this is happening , I thought using a vector would prevent overwriting elements

```
            while(rs.next())
            {

                int ID=rs.getInt("ID");
                String Nom=rs.getString("Nom");
                String Prenom=rs.getString("Prenom");
                int Age=rs.getInt("Age");

                etudiant.setID(ID);
                etudiant.setNom(Nom);
                etudiant.setPrenom(Prenom);
                etudiant.setAge(Age);

                v.add(etudiant);

                for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
                {
                    etudiant etdd=v.elementAt(i);
                    String nom =etdd.getNom();
                    String prenom=etdd.getPrenom();
                    int age=etdd.getAge();
                    int id=etdd.getID();

                }   

            }
```

here is the code I used to display the content of my vector (in my Main)

```
Vector<etudiant> vctr=DAO.GetEtudiants();
    for(int i=0;i<vctr.size();i++)
    {
        etudiant etdd=vctr.elementAt(i);
        String nom =etdd.getNom();
        String prenom=etdd.getPrenom();
        int age=etdd.getAge();
        int id=etdd.getID();
        System.out.println("ID: "+id+"   |Nom: "+nom+"      |Prenom: "+prenom+"   |Age: "+age);

    }
```

Comment: You need to post `etudiant`; when you say `v.add(etudiant);` you don't appear to have created an instance in your loop.... this code looks specious.

Comment: Please, respect the Java naming conventions, and don't use Vector.  It's obsolete since Java 2. We're at Java 8. Use an ArrayList.

Comment: Everytime the loop executes, you simply replace the values of etudiant object with the new values in the vector. You have to allocate a new **etudiant object** everytime the loop iterates.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , I created the object 'etudiant' right before entering the loop

Comment: @ShayHaned, I don't understand your comment, I've written the loop so that at each iteration, the object receives new values, and this object is put in a new cell, isn't that what this code does?

Comment: you have to create the object 'etudiant' inside the loop

Comment: @A.Bukhari Yes, it receives new values, but looses the previous one. So inside your loop before assigning new values, just say **etudiant = new etudiant()**, and then assign the values, that's exactly what ElliotFrisch pointed out

Comment: Yes it works fine now,thanks a lot, but could you please tell me the mistake in declaring 'etudiant' outside the loop?I thought  'etudiant' stores its values in a cell before it receives new ones...

Comment: Actually, I understand now, I was filling the entire array with the same object, so each time I modify the object, the whole array receives the new values. Interresting! Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @A.Bukhari Great!, You got it now!!